# How to access a domain system, if system is using wifi

Tags: networking, monitoring, windows-server

I have my own **Windows Server 2012 R2** with Active Directory having 150+ users. Right now we are using Net Monitors for employee Pro to monitor our users,

**My Question is if one my user's laptop is using Wifi instead of LAN Cable, is there any way I can access or I can Monitor.**

.

Comment: Why do you expect it would be any different?

Comment: you will need some form of unified network management. there isn't just a setting that can turn on that will fix this.

Comment: I'm with @user1686: what makes you think it would be different? Is there actually a specific problem that you are trying to solve? Please tell us your real problem and we'll try to solve it.

Comment: Alright, let me brief the issue, I have my own server with 150+ user, all users are connected to internet via networking through LAN cable. all users have static IP. so if users are connected to internet via LAN form our network so we can access to their systems and can monitor via Net Monitors for employee Pro Software.

But in case if users or connected to internet out of networking, like Wi-Fi, so we don't have any access to them.